# Get specific view in custom directory .NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, asp.net-core-mvc

So I've already done it, but is there any other way without '.cshtml' extension ?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ENehE.png

```
      [HttpGet("erm/nama-project/dashboard")]
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewBag.Current = "Dashboard";
            return View("/Views/Nama-Project/index.cshtml");
        }
```

Comment: I'm pasting the images because I want to show my directory folder also with the code..

k I'll paste the code too..

Comment: for more information about pasting code, see here https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question

Comment: What do you want to achieve exactly ? What would you like to do ?

Comment: acces the view file and remove .cshtml in code.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve, what is the problem you are trying to solve by "removing cshtml" ?

Comment: I used to work with Laravel or CI, I just don't like writing the file extension every I acces the view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want to remove `cshtml` extension while specifying the view name, you can create a base controller and override View method as shown below:

```
public override ViewResult View(string nameWithoutExtension)
{
   return base.View($"{nameWithoutExtension}.cshtml")
}
```

Comment: thanks, works like a charm !!, can you explain how it works please ?

Comment: @Maulana the syntax `$"{nameWithoutExtension}.cshtml"` is called a "string interpolation". It's equivalent to `nameWithoutExtension + ".cshtml"`, but arguably clearer. Otherwise the function itself overrides (replaces) the base `View()` function that you were calling, the `return base.View` ensures that it actually returns the same thing under the hood.

Answer (score 1):

Alternate to @user12937005 's answer, you can always use

```
return View("Action", "Controller");
```

If they are in the same controller, to save time, use

```
return View("Action");
```

I hope this help. This is not to nullify the previous answer but to fulfill learning purpose and give alternative